# A limit on x and y

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that $\mbox{lim}_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}$ doesn't exist. Someone can help me with this? I've tried with polar coordinates and the only problem is that limit doesn't exist when I'm not in the domain.

Comment: Factoring the numerator should help.

Comment: That function is not defined in a deleted neighborhood of $(0,0)$ How could it have a limit there?

Comment: Change variables $(x,y) \to  (x, y) = (y+h, y)$.

Comment: Because in the domain, the limit is always 0, or not? Taking any neighborhood $B$, $B \cap \mbox{Dom}\left(\dfrac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}\right)=A$, the imagens of the elements of A are approaching 0...

Comment: @zhw. The confusion might be as follows.  The function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x}$ is not defined at the origin.  But surely its limit as $x\to 0$ exists and is equal to $0$.  Now, for the problem in the OP, the limit does not exist.  But not simply because it is undefined at the origin.

Comment: @DrMV I didn't say that. I said it's not defined in a deleted neighborhood of (0,0). Note that $x^2/x$ is defined in a deleted neighborhood of 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that the limit does not exist, simply approach $0$ along the path $y=x-x^4$.  Then, we have

$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y}=\frac{x^3+(x-x^4)^3}{x^4}$$

Can you finish this now?

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $-x^4$ in the denom? Not that it makes a difference for the outcome though

Comment: @imranfat I changed the path to $y=x-x^4$ and edited.  Thank you for the nice catch.  -Mark